# creating one data frame using Pandas for multiple CSV files from many URL's

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I'd like to create 1 data frame/structure using Pandas from multiple CSV files from URL's, keeping the initial header line.

With a single URL everything works as expected:

```
df = pd.read_csv('http://www.URL1.csv')
```

I have attempted the following with multiple URL's:

```
df = pd.read_csv('http://www.URL1.csv', 'http://www.URL2.csv', ...)
```

However, when attempting to print for testing, the result is spaced out over thousands of lines and is far from the standard layout. Since I am new to `Pandas`, it is clear I am doing something wrong.

---

I'd expect the layout to be as followed:

```
Header1 Header2 Header3 ...
DATA    DATA    DATA    ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need `list comprehension` with `list` of `urls` where output is `list` of `DataFrames`. Then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for join together:

```
urls = ['http://www.URL1.csv', 'http://www.URL2.csv']
dfs = [pd.read_csv(url) for url in urls]

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: That's amazing! Works like a charm! Is there any chance you could explain the need for list comprehension?

Comment: You need list comprehension if need apply some function like `read_csv` for each element of another list of elemens.

Comment: ... output of list comprehension is list of outputs (dataframes) which return function (like read_csv). And fastest way for create dataframe from list of dataframes is concat.

Comment: Thanks, is there a purpose behind `ignore_index=True`? I can't seem to spot the difference

Comment: You can avoid duplicates in index. Please check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#ignoring-indexes-on-the-concatenation-axis)